# Multiple parameters in macro

Tags: c, macros

I am trying to simplify writing my embedded programs in C. How would I create a macro that could accept any number or parameters up from 2?

I currently have this:

```
#define P_PIN_HIGH(pin_letter, pin_num)         (PORT##pin_letter |= (1 << pin_num))
#define PIN_HIGH(...)           P_PIN_HIGH(__VA_ARGS__)
```

And I can use this like so:

```
#define PIN_TEST    A, 0    // Every pin gets defined this way.

PIN_HIGH(PIN_TEST);         // Set this pin to high.
```

But, I would like to be able to pass any number of pins(they must have the same letter) to the macro,  like so:

```
#define PIN_TEST     A, 0
#define PIN_TEST1    A, 1
#define PIN_TEST2    A, 2

PIN_HIGH(PIN_TEST, PIN_TEST1, PIN_TEST2);
```

So, the compiled code, would look like this:

```
PORTA |= ((1<<0) | (1<<1) | (1<<2));
```

Is this doable?

Comment: Do you mean "number of paramaters" >= 2? In this case it's possible. The syntax is: `#define MACRO(A, B, ...)` and then inside the macro the part corresponding to `...` is obtained, again, with `__VA_ARGS__`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable arguements in macro using ellipsis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514201/variable-arguements-in-macro-using-ellipsis)

Comment: No, not a duplicate. By bigger >= 2, I just meant that at least one  pin has to be passed to macro.

Comment: Oh, sorry, then use: `#define MACRO(PIN1, __VA_ARGS__)`.

Comment: I am sorry, I dont get it...

Answer (score 1):

not really. If you can use c++ then it's very easy with templates.

```
template <volatile char *port_, size_t bit_number_>
struct port_descriptor
{
    static constexpr size_t bit_number = bit_number_;
    static volatile char *const port;
};
template <volatile char *port_, size_t bit_number_>
volatile char *const port_descriptor<port_, bit_number_>::port = port_;

typedef port_descriptor<&PORTA, 0> PIN_TEST;

template <class ...args>
char get_set_port_value(bool new_value);

template <class ...args>
void set_port_value(bool new_value);

template <volatile char *port_, size_t bit_number_>
char get_set_port_value<port_descriptor<port_, bit_number_>>(bool new_value)
{
    char v = *port_;
    if(new_value)
        return v | 1 << bit_number_;
    return v & ~(1 << bit_number_);
}

template <volatile char *port_, size_t bit_number_, class ...Args>
char get_set_port_value<port_descriptor<port_, bit_number_>, Args...>(bool new_value)
{
    char v = get_set_port_value<Args...>();
    if(new_value)
        return v | 1 << bit_number_;
    return v & ~(1 << bit_number_);
}

template <volatile char *port_, size_t bit_number_, class ...Args>
void set_port_value<port_descriptor<port_, bit_number_>, Args...>(bool new_value)
{
    char v = get_set_port_value<port_descriptor<port_, bit_number_>, Args...>(new_value);
    *port_ = v;
}
```

then you can do `set_port_value<PIN_TEST>(true);`

Comment: No, its a program for a microcontroller.

Comment: which microcontroller?

Comment: 8-bit AVR, it would be an overkill to use C++.

Comment: I have always used avr-g++ and arduino is actually C++.

Comment: I am not using arduino. I am programming "raw AVR".

Comment: that's what avr-g++ is. just use g++ instead of gcc.

Answer (score 0):

Your P_PIN_HIGH() macro seems to take only two arguments. In your [variadic macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html#Variadic-Macros) PIN_HIGH, you are passing 3 argument pairs which, as per that macro's definition, would be passed as arguments to P_PIN_HIGH (which expects only 2 arguments). Seems like you would want to iterate over your argument pairs, in your P_PIN_HIGH() macro, by explicitly passing the number of argument pairs.

Comment: Yes, that's right, I would want to iterate. How would I accomplish that?